# How to authorize webapp with ebay?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ebay-api

I am making a django app that can hold info about items i have on ebay.
So, each user would have multiple ebay accounts. 
For example:
user1 would have access to ebay1, ebay2, ebay3 account.
How can I get appid, certid, devid and token for each account?
The best would be to click 'add ebay account' and in new window with ebay sign in page and authorize by inserting username/password.

I had a look to:

https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python

https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/FetchToken.html

but it is not clear to me. 
Can anyone provide me some step-by-step or any guidelines?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Can anyone provide me some step-by-step` don't you have to many points to write stuff like this? you should know that this is not going to happen. 

To your question: You need to check the API of eBay they will provide all necessary Information. Fetch the Data with Ajax... 
Take a look at a tutorial or something
[link]https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=api+ebay

Comment: Thanks for inditcations. I found very helpful [https://github.com/luke-dixon/django-ebay-accounts](https://github.com/luke-dixon/django-ebay-accounts). But i cannot go further because i get `InvalidHeader at /ebay_accounts/begin_create
Header value 3 must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'int'>` error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used code from this repo: https://github.com/luke-dixon/django-ebay-accounts
with fix from: [here](https://github.com/luke-dixon/django-ebay-accounts/commit/f4913039b452cef9315f3f4deced89f09203afb4) it works great

Answer (score 1):

```
InvalidHeader at /ebay_accounts/begin_create Header value 3 must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'int'>
```

you have to append the str to your data you send so str("whatever")

Answer (score 0):

You simply login to the developer account and then Click User Tokens.

next click Get a User Token Here.

login to each account you need a token for

your APPID, CertId, and DevID always stay the same..